# Populating a Three Dimensional Dictionary gives weird Results in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to fill my Three-Dimensional Dictionary inside of a Loop, where I iterate through the years, months and ItemCategories.

```
Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int, Dictionary<ItemCategories, List<ExpenseStatisticItem>>>> ExpenseItemsData

ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category].Add(item);
```

While Debugging following is being called:

```
ExpenseItemsData[2016][3][ItemCategory.Food].Add("Bla");
```

Now somehow it doesn't put the Entry where I told him to, but instead it gets put in every Entry of the Dictionary where Category == Food. Somehow the Years and  the Months get completely ignored.

What am I missing?

Here is the full code:

```
        string currentDate = "";
        int currentMonth = 0;
        int currentYear = 0;
        string fileName = "DynamischeAusgaben.txt";


        var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/MeineDaten/FinanzProgramm/Statistik/");
        var years = directory.GetDirectories();

        foreach (var year in years)
        {
            currentYear = int.Parse(year.Name);

            if (currentYear == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            directory = new DirectoryInfo(String.Format("C:/MeineDaten/FinanzProgramm/Statistik/{0}/", currentYear));
            var months = directory.GetDirectories();

            foreach (var month in months)
            {
                currentMonth = int.Parse(month.Name);

                if (currentMonth == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int dayCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);
                List<string> dayDates = new List<string>();

                // Datums der verschiedenen Tage dieses Monats zusammenstellen
                for (int i = 1; i < dayCount + 1; i++)
                {
                    dayDates.Add(new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, i, 0, 0, 0).ToShortDateString());
                }

                string path = string.Format("C:/MeineDaten/FinanzProgramm/Statistik/{0}/{1}/DynamischeAusgaben",
                    currentYear, currentMonth);
                bool fileExists = File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, fileName));

                if (!fileExists)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                string data = "";
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
                {
                    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    data = data.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
                }

                foreach (var date in dayDates)
                {
                    // Wenn das Datum nicht in der Datei enthalten ist, geh weiter.
                    if (!data.Contains(date))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    string[] days = data.Split(';');

                    for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // Leere Zeile ignorieren
                        if (days[i] == "")
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string[] dayAndCategories = days[i].Split('<');
                        string dayString = dayAndCategories[0];

                        for (int j = 1; j < dayAndCategories.Length; j++)
                        {
                            string[] categoryAndItems = dayAndCategories[j].Split('|');

                            ItemCategories category = (ItemCategories)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemCategories), categoryAndItems[0]);
                            decimal total = decimal.Parse(categoryAndItems[1]);

                            string[] itemsAndNothing = categoryAndItems[2].Split('>');


                            for (int k = 0; k < itemsAndNothing.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (itemsAndNothing[k] == "")
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                string[] itemvalues = itemsAndNothing[1].Split('#');

                                ExpenseStatisticItem item = new ExpenseStatisticItem
                                {
                                    Name = itemvalues[0],
                                    Total = decimal.Parse(itemvalues[1]),
                                    Count = int.Parse(itemvalues[2])
                                };


                                bool matchFound = false;
                                int matchIndex = 0;

                                // Ermitteln ob es schon ein Item mit diesem Namen in diesem Monat und Kategorie gibt
                                for (int l = 0; l < Global.ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category].Count; l++)
                                {
                                    ExpenseStatisticItem itemToCompare = Global.ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category][l];

                                    if (itemToCompare.Name == item.Name)
                                    {
                                        matchFound = true;
                                        matchIndex = l;
                                    }
                                }

                                // Wenn es schon ein Item gibt, dann fasse die Items zusammen
                                if (matchFound)
                                {
                                    Global.ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category][matchIndex].Count += item.Count;
                                    Global.ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category][matchIndex].Total += item.Total;
                                }
                                // Ansonsten erstelle einen neuen Eintrag
                                else
                                {

                                    Global.ExpenseItemsData[currentYear][currentMonth][category].Add(item);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please tag your question with a programming language, and please provide more code so we can determine where the issue is.

Comment: can you add the loop you wrote, and I would advice to create a structure or class instead of using what you call a three dimensiona Dictionary...

Comment: How do you create the dictionary?

Comment: Likely you have reused the same `List` object in each case instead of creating a new one so they all point to the same list for a given food type.

Comment: BTW, unless your access pattern is always Y>M>C, this nested dictionary approach might not be a good one. A simple `List<ExpenseItem>` and LINQ Where clauses to filter by year, month or food type or any combination thereof would be easier to code, more readable and more flexible.

Comment: More code needed